# Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:parseReleaseLibraryResources'

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:parseReleaseLibraryResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\zenqi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\zenqi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 40s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

I'm having that kind of error. I'm really confused why it gives me that kind of error? is this a library error or no?

Here are my `dependencies`

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.5",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "genius-lyrics-api": "^3.0.2",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-native": "^0.62.2",
        "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
        "react-native-get-music-files": "https://github.com/cinder92/react-native-get-music-files.git#master",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
        "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
        "react-native-masked-view": "^0.2.0",
        "react-native-material-menu": "^1.1.3",
        "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
        "react-native-quick-scroll": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
        "react-native-share": "^3.7.0",
        "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
        "react-native-track-player": "1.2.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
        "underscore": "^1.10.2"
}
```